# Creating an ArrayList of ArrayList having one additional element compared to another ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, pass-by-reference

I have an ArrayList of ArrayList (alal) and an ArrayList(al). I want to insert al to alal, but I want alal.get(0) to contain everything al has plus the element 100 added. I thought the easiest way to do this, is to first do

> alal.add(al);

and then access it's 0th element, and add a 100, like

> alal.get(0).add(100);

However, the problem with this is that al's contents also change since it's an Object and so alal holds it's reference and not the value.

I have tried below. Please tell me if this is the right way to do it, or suggest improvements.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class additionalal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> alal = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        al.add(1);al.add(2);al.add(3);

        //WRONG
//      alal.add(al);
//      alal.get(0).add(100);

        //CORRECT
        ArrayList<Integer> alextra = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        alextra.addAll(al);
        alextra.add(100);
        alal.add(alextra);

        System.out.println(alal);
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: If you want alal.get(0) to return the contents of the list al, then you should insert al (actually a copy of it) into element 0: `alal.add(0, al)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your list into a new `ArrayList` when adding, thus cloning it:

```
alal.add(new ArrayList<>(al));
alal.get(0).add(100);
```

Note though, that the elements of the list are not cloned with it. This is ok when you have lists of `Integer`s, but can result in unexpected behaviour when storing elements of type that has dynamic properties. For example, consider you want to store a `List` of `List`s of `Person`s:

```
class Person {
    String name = "";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String otherName) {
        this.name = otherName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person[name=" + this.name + ']';
    }
}
```

Now, I create a `Person`, put it into a `List` `persons`, then I put a copy of `persons` in, say, `personGroups`:

```
Person user = new Person();
user.setName("saltandwater");

List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add(user);

List<List<Person>> personGroups = new ArrayList<>();
personGroups.add(new ArrayList<>(persons));
```

Printing both lists will result in something like

```
persons: [Person[name=saltandwater]]
personGroups: [[Person[name=saltandwater]]]
```

Now, adding new `Person` into `persons` won't modify `personGroups`. But, since the `user` was not cloned (only the `persons` list was cloned), the changes in `user.name` will be reflected in both lists:

```
user.setName("Mr. Yetti");
```

will result in

```
persons: [Person[name=Mr. Yetti]]
personGroups: [[Person[name=Mr. Yetti]]]
```

Comment: thanks this is very nice. But what do you mean when you say, "Note though, that the elements of the list are not cloned with it."
 I see all the element in alal, ie, [[1, 2, 3, 100]].

Comment: @saltandwater: Enhanced the answer. This is not particularly relevant in your situation, but still not bad to keep in mind.